# Stored procedure, dealing with insert and update, is this impossible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-update, insert-update

I have two tables with the exact same columns.

Both have primary identity keys called id that auto increment.

My program adds data to a stagging table and then filters what gets added to the task table through this procedure.

Mmy problem is
I have this update statement followed by an insert,
for some reason my update statement does not work, when it is in the procedure by itself.

My insert statement works when it is by itself in the procedure but not when underneath this update statement.

I want my update statement to

Update my duedate in my dashboardtasks table, 
if these 3 fields match in the row
tour
deptdate
taskname

If the row being added does not match in these 3 fields than insert the row as a new row using my insert statement underneath.

```
 update dashboardtasks set
         deptdate = s.deptdate,
         tour = s.tour,
          tasktype = s.tasktype,
          [desc] = s.[desc],
          duedate = s.duedate,
          compdate = s.compdate,
          comments = s.comments,
          agent = s.agent,
          compby = s.compby,
          graceperiod    = s.graceperiod
        from staggingtasks as s
        where
          s.tour=dashboardtasks.tour and
          s.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname and 
          s.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate 


        insert into dashboardtasks (tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
        select tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod
        from staggingtasks as s
        where not exists (select *
                          from dashboardtasks as d
                          where s.tour=d.tour and
                                s.taskname=d.taskname and 
                                s.deptdate=d.deptdate and
                                s.duedate=d.duedate
                         )


id int Unchecked
tour varchar(50) Checked
taskname varchar(50) Checked
deptdate varchar(50) Checked
tasktype varchar(50) Checked
[desc] varchar(MAX) Checked
duedate varchar(50) Checked
compdate varchar(50) Checked
comments varchar(MAX) Checked
agent varchar(50) Checked
compby varchar(50) Checked
graceperiod varchar(50) Checked
```

these are my fields, but compby, comments, compdate, and desc are null

Comment: Just as a nitpick: what you're using would be called a "staging" table - not "stagging" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a run through with your queries.

Set up test data

```
create table dashboardtasks1(id int identity, tour int, taskname nvarchar(50), deptdate datetime, tasktype nvarchar(50), [desc] nvarchar(50), duedate datetime, compdate datetime, comments nvarchar(50), agent nvarchar(50), compby int, graceperiod int)
create table staggingtasks(id int, tour int, taskname nvarchar(50), deptdate datetime, tasktype nvarchar(50), [desc] nvarchar(50), duedate datetime, compdate datetime, comments nvarchar(50), agent nvarchar(50), compby int, graceperiod int)

insert into staggingtasks(id, tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (62, 3647, 'Request Space', '2011-03-30', 'Land', NULL, '2010-01-06', NULL, NULL, 'PEGGYH', NULL, NULL)
insert into staggingtasks(id, tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (81, 505, 'Rel. Space', '2012-02-22', 'Land', NULL, '2011-12-24', NULL, NULL, 'IMANA', NULL, NULL)
insert into staggingtasks(id, tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (82, 505, 'Ticket', '2012-02-22', 'Air', NULL, '2012-01-08', NULL, NULL, 'SYLVIAT', NULL, NULL)
insert into staggingtasks(id, tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (83, 505, 'Names to Airlines', '2012-02-22', 'Air', NULL, '2012-01-08', NULL, NULL, 'SYLVIAT', NULL, NULL)
insert into staggingtasks(id, tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (90, 505, 'Names to Airlines', '2012-02-22', 'Air', NULL, '2012-01-01', NULL, NULL, 'SYLVIAT', NULL, NULL)
insert into staggingtasks(id, tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (92, 505, 'Names to Airlines', '2012-02-22', 'Air', NULL, '2012-01-01', NULL, NULL, 'SYLVIAT', NULL, NULL)

insert into dashboardtasks1(tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (3647, 'Request Space', '2011-03-30', 'Land', NULL, '2010-11-06', NULL, NULL, 'PEGGYH', NULL, NULL)
insert into dashboardtasks1(tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (505, 'Rel. Space', '2012-02-22', 'Land', NULL, '2011-11-24', NULL, NULL, 'IMANA', NULL, NULL)
insert into dashboardtasks1(tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (505, 'Ticket', '2012-02-22', 'Air', NULL, '2012-11-08', NULL, NULL, 'SYLVIAT', NULL, NULL)
insert into dashboardtasks1(tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
    values (505, 'Names to Airlines', '2012-02-22', 'Air', NULL, '2012-11-08', NULL, NULL, 'SYLVIAT', NULL, NULL)
```

Run the update statement

```
update dashboardtasks1 set
  tasktype = s.tasktype,
  [desc] = s.[desc],
  duedate = s.duedate,
  compdate = s.compdate,
  comments = s.comments,
  agent = s.agent,
  compby = s.compby,
  graceperiod    = s.graceperiod
from staggingtasks as s
where
  s.tour=dashboardtasks1.tour and
  s.taskname=dashboardtasks1.taskname and 
  s.deptdate=dashboardtasks1.deptdate
```

Four rows affected. A select from dashboardtasks1 gives you this result

```
id  tour    taskname    deptdate    tasktype    desc    duedate compdate    comments    agent   compby  graceperiod
1   3647    Request Space   2011-03-30 00:00:00.000 Land    NULL    2010-01-06 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    PEGGYH  NULL    NULL
2   505 Rel. Space  2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Land    NULL    2011-12-24 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    IMANA   NULL    NULL
3   505 Ticket  2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Air NULL    2012-01-08 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT NULL    NULL
4   505 Names to Airlines   2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Air NULL    2012-01-08 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT NULL    NULL
```

Run the insert statement

```
insert into dashboardtasks1 (tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
select tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod
from staggingtasks as s
where not exists (select *
                  from dashboardtasks1 as d
                  where s.tour=d.tour and
                        s.taskname=d.taskname and 
                        s.deptdate=d.deptdate and
                        s.duedate=d.duedate
                 )
```

Two rows are affected. A query against dashboardtasks1 gives you this result.

```
id  tour    taskname    deptdate    tasktype    desc    duedate compdate    comments    agent   compby  graceperiod
1   3647    Request Space   2011-03-30 00:00:00.000 Land    NULL    2010-01-06 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    PEGGYH  NULL    NULL
2   505 Rel. Space  2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Land    NULL    2011-12-24 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    IMANA   NULL    NULL
3   505 Ticket  2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Air NULL    2012-01-08 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT NULL    NULL
4   505 Names to Airlines   2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Air NULL    2012-01-08 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT NULL    NULL
5   505 Names to Airlines   2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Air NULL    2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT NULL    NULL
6   505 Names to Airlines   2012-02-22 00:00:00.000 Air NULL    2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT NULL    NULL
```

Is this the expected behavior/result?

Comment: Try in an empty db with the tables and the test data in the answer. Compare the structure of your tables against mine. Are you using datetime fields etc?

Comment: sweet it works the only thing i didnt account for is that if my stagging table has duplicates the update isnt going to work properly, i may just add a field in the staging table that gives the rowcreated as a datetime and just have the update select the most recent, row for the update

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing it out there, but have you tried replacing the where clause with an inner join?
Something like this:

```
update dashboardtasks set
     deptdate = s.deptdate,
     tour = s.tour,
      tasktype = s.tasktype,
      [desc] = s.[desc],
      duedate = s.duedate,
      compdate = s.compdate,
      comments = s.comments,
      agent = s.agent,
      compby = s.compby,
      graceperiod    = s.graceperiod
    from staggingtasks as s
    inner join dashboardtasks on
      s.tour=dashboardtasks.tour and
      s.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname and 
      s.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate
```

Comment: hmm it still doesnt update, so weird why can a table not be updateable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in a SELECT statement between the UPDATE and INSERT statements? It might give you some clues as to why the procedure isn't working as you expect.

Also the `s.duedate=d.duedate` part of your where clause is probably redundant.

Comment: hmm what kind of select statement. and do you think i could create my stored procedure differently using ifs?

Comment: Mikael's answer is what I meant by putting in a select; he selected all the data after each operation so you can see what's going on. You could restructure using if statements which would have the advantage of being easier to read and understand the next time you need to edit it. It will reduce the speed at which the procedure executes though.